# keyboard command functionality with libtcod c++

Tags: c++, libtcod

I recently switched from SFML to libtcod for my rougelike, because i find libtcod more convinient for those kinds of games. One problem i cant find any solution for is how to store keyboard bound functions.

In SFML i could do this for my keyfunctions

```
std::map<sf::Keyboard::Key, std::function<void()>> keyboardCommands
```

In libtcod there's the TCOD_Key_t struct (that would replace sf::Keyboard::Key in the map) which works for special keys like F-keys, Esc, etc. [but "nothing" for letters.](http://roguecentral.org/doryen/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.1/html2/console_keycode_t.html?c=false&cpp=true&cs=false&py=false&lua=false)

Is there a way with libtcod i could put all my keyboard functions in one map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I have never used this library!

I found [this](http://roguecentral.org/doryen/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.0/console/keycode_t.html):

```
Any other (printable) key :
TCODK_CHAR
```

So when you receive `TCODK_CHAR`, you look for `char c;` from [this struct](http://roguecentral.org/doryen/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.0/console/key_t.html):

```
typedef struct {
    TCOD_keycode_t vk;
    char c;
    unsigned pressed : 1;
    unsigned lalt : 1;
    unsigned lctrl : 1;
    unsigned ralt : 1;
    unsigned rctrl : 1;
    unsigned shift : 1;
} TCOD_key_t;
```

I believe it will contain character pressed.

**UPDATE**

It's a C library, so intended usage is probably was something like:
(`key` here is of type `TCOD_key_t`)

```
switch(key.vk) {
    case TCODK_UP : onUp(); break;
    case TCODK_CHAR: onChar(key.c); break
    default: break;
}
```

With map you could do something like:

```
if(TCODK_CHAR == key.vk)
    onChar(key.c);
else
    specialCommands[key.vk]();
```

(where
`specialCommands` is `std::map<TCOD_keycode_t, std::function<...> >`
)

You might put `char` callbacks tinto the map, however, if some of the members of `TCOD_keycode_t` enumeration will match character code, you will have a key collision (i.e. if, hypothetically `TCODK_UP` has value `65`, it will be the same key as char `'a'` (ASCII code `65`)).

You could also have another `map` or `array` that maps characters (`key.c`) to different functions.

Comment: How would i put that into one map? Special keys would need TCOD_keycode_t and characters would need c. What i can think about is that i'd have a map for TCOD_keycode_t-s and one for chars. and in my event cheking, check if c is empty, and then check the appropriate map.

Comment: @val added dome more info